# Meta tags not showing in page source in next js

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

Meta tags are showing in Element but not in page Source. I have to share post in social media but due to meta tags not working i can't share post.

Meta tags are showing in Element but not in page Source. When I change the _app.tsx code from

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate persistor={store.__PERSISTOR} loading={<GlobalLoader />}>
    <Layout>
      {isLoading && <GlobalLoader />}
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <ToastContainer />
    </Layout>
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

to

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate persistor={store.__PERSISTOR} loading={<GlobalLoader />}>
    {() => (
      <Layout>
        {isLoading && <GlobalLoader />}
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <ToastContainer />
      </Layout>
    )}
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

Meta tags shows in page source but i got dehydration error, which i can't resolved. Because the project is too big and i can't identified why dehydration error occurs. Kindly help me in this issue. Thanks